# Cisco ASA privilege level for object-groups

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I'm trying to set-up privilege level 2, so that it has access to read and modify object and object-groups. Showing them seems to be no problem. I can also enter configure mode. I just can't get the '`object-group network blah`' command to work (it shows as unauthorized). However, I've come across something odd. I did the following and found what I thought to be the correct line to change:

```
ciscoasa# sh run all priv all
```

...
    privilege cmd level 15 mode configure command object-group
...

But, when I try to apply this:

```
ciscoasa(config)# privilege cmd level 2 mode configure command object-group
ERROR: specified command 'object-group' not found in mode 'configure'.
```

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Seems to be a bug/"feature" because it didn't work on my home v8.4 but does work on our data centre v8.6